# Stuff not showing up until render, and is not hidden (tried alt+H)

Tags: rendering

Only the ball and goal showing up, not plane. Have no idea what I clicked
[image: only ball and goal showing up, not plane. Have no idea what I clicked]

I watched it randomly disappear. I don't know what I clicked, other than maybe P. But I don't think clicking P would've made it disappear, as I didn't even have the plane that isn't showing up selected. Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure because you cropped off Outliner panel in your screenshot, but I suspect you turned the grass off using the "Hide in Viewport" eyeball. If the "eyeball" is closed e.g. u shaped like it is in the Outliner panel below, click on it so it becomes **open** like the others.

[image: The outliner]

Comment: Sorry abt the crop, it said my picture was too large with it in. Unfortuantly, the eye is open on my screen for the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was in "local view" easy fix, just clicked forward slash"/"